# Modify object in Mongoose pre-save hook

Tags: typescript, mongoose, geojson

In a GeoJSON Polygon (or more strictly: LinearRing), the last set of coordinates needs to evaluate to the same value as the first one:

```
[[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0]] // bad
[[0,0], [0,1], [1,1], [1,0], [0,0]] // good
```

I would like to do some lenient validation (i.e. fixing the object, instead of rejecting it) when saving a GeoJSON Polygon to my MongoDB instance with Mongoose.

I do this:

```
export type Coordinates = number[]

// model object
export class Polygon { 
  type: string;
  coordinates?: Coordinates[];

  constructor(coordinates?: Coordinates[]) {
    this.type = "Polygon";
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
  }
}

// schema object
export const PolygonSchema = { 
  type: String,
  coordinates: [[Number]],
};

// model-schema binding
const polygonSchema = new mongoose.Schema(PolygonSchema, { typeKey: '$type' }).loadClass(Polygon);

// pre-save hook
polygonSchema.pre('save', async (next, opts) => {
  // @ts-ignore
  const pol: Polygon = this; // I find this assignment everywhere in documentation, but it seems to fail
  if (pol?.coordinates?.length > 1 && pol.coordinates[0] !== pol.coordinates[pol.coordinates.length - 1]) {
    pol.coordinates.push(pol.coordinates[0]);
  }
  next();
});
```

`tsc` complains that `this` will always be undefined, and the `pol` object is indeed undefined when debugging. However, `this` is not, according to the Visual Studio debugger.

[image: Conflicting evidence in the debugger]

Is it possible to modify the object during the pre-save hook, or do I need to do this beforehand ?

A note, in case it matters: a Polygon will always be a *subdocument* in my MongoDB instance: it is saved as the shape of another object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pre('save', ...)` function won't give you access to the document if you pass it an arrow function instead of a traditional function. Arrow functions do not have `this` bound, and instead use the parent scope.

From [mozilla dev docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

> Arrow functions don't have their own bindings to this, arguments or super, and should not be used as methods.

Change your arrow to a traditional function definition

From

```
polygonSchema.pre('save', {document: true, query: true}, async (next, opts) => {...}
```

To

```
polygonSchema.pre('save', {document: true, query: true}, async function (next, opts) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'd just found the solution myself, but I'm accepting yours since you provide both the reason and the fix.

Comment: @blagae Thank you - it's my big problem with answering recent questions. You just know there's 5 other people typing up a similar answer at the same time as yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a problem that I did not expect. Apparently, you have no access to the `this` object in anonymous (arrow) functions ( source: https://youtu.be/DZBGEVgL2eE?t=1495 ). I don't know if this means in JavaScript in general or Mongoose, specifically, but the problem was fixed by doing this:

```
const polygonSchema = new mongoose.Schema(PolygonSchema, { typeKey: '$type' }).loadClass(Polygon);

async function preSave() {
  // @ts-ignore
  const pol: Polygon = this;
  if (pol?.coordinates?.length && pol.coordinates[0] !== pol.coordinates[pol.coordinates.length - 1]) {
    pol.coordinates.push(pol.coordinates[0]);
  }
}

polygonSchema.pre('save', preSave);
```